Error authenticating with Fixie proxy: '407 Proxy Authentication Required'
I've setup Fixie for use on a Heroku app. I have a Node app and using Axios to make service calls and https-proxy-agent to configure the proxy settings:
const fixieUrl = new URL(process.env.FIXIE_URL);
console.log(`Fixie URL: ${process.env.FIXIE_URL}`);

const proxyOpts = {
  host: fixieUrl.hostname,
  port: fixieUrl.port || 80,
  headers: {
    "Proxy-Authentication":
      "Basic " +
      Buffer.from(`${fixieUrl.username}:${fixieUrl.password}`).toString(
        "base64"
      ),
  },
};

const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyOpts);

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    proxy: false,
    httpsAgent,
    headers: {
      Authorization: authHeader,
    },
  });


When I attempt to make any call with the axiosInstance I get this error:
'407 Proxy Authentication Required'
I can see from my logging statement that the fixieUrl is correct and in the right format:
http://fixie:xxxxxxxxxx@velodrome.usefixie.com:80
I have also tried using the .auth with plaintext:
proxyOpts.auth = 'username:password';
I get the same result.
